# How to run QTQuick test

Tags: qt5, qtquick2, qtestlib

how can I run tests for QtQuick-Applications in the main.cpp? The main.qml have a rectangle and inside some buttons. The test class MouseClick.qml implements the javascript test functions who should push the buttons.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QTestCase = QTestCase(MouseClick); //????

    QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/TestApp/main.qml"));
    viewer.showExpanded();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to look how tests are implemented in Qt. [For example](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtdeclarative/source/dabe6288f090072d4d50f894a5f850f6fb8051c1%3atests/auto/qml/qqmlinstantiator/tst_qqmlinstantiator.cpp#L199)

Comment: The only way I've found is use the QUICK_TEST_MAIN macro for starting without this macro i get a compiler error..

Comment: It's common practive to put test code into another executable. Anyway, I don't see any reason why you can't execute code in link manually. And get rid of this ApplicationViewer! It hides implementation details which every beginner should know.